Neural Networks for LIDAR Images
I recently encountered this blog https://ouster.com/insights/blog/the-camera-is-in-the-lidar
It seems like one can leverage lidar data as an image quite nicely and therefore use 2D vision algorithms instead of pointclouds for many tasks.
I'm just surprised that I can't seem to find any works on the subject.
Anyone happen to know of some sources that have tested out this ability? Or has it only been used by companies like Ouster who wrote the blog for a bit of publicity?
